# Why django inspectdb doesn't create foreign keys correctly on an existing database?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, migration, legacy-database

I want to use an existing database but after `inspectdb` generates an auto generated models file the relations of the models are not according to django.

For example:

```
user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

which should be a foreign key:

```
user_id = models.Foreignkey('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Is the relationship defined at the database level ?

Comment: No. But when I try to make that integer field a foreign key in the models.py, the following error occurs: (1054, "Unknown column 'inquiry.company_id_id' in 'field list'").

Comment: Use user instead of user_id